# Unseen value in a feature vector for training set which is present in test set

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining

I have a dataset that contains a feature vector pertaining to salutations given to a person for e.g. Mr, Mrs etc. I am using this feature vector to make predictions on the ages of these individuals but my training set does not contain all the values that I see in the test set. I have considered the approach where i can combine the values of this particular feature vector from both my test set and train set but I do not want to do this, i think this is cheating, because we are using information from the test set in our train set. I would really like to have some inputs as to how to solve the problem.

All values present in the training set:

```
levels(as.factor(x$Salutation))
 [1] "Capt"     "Col"      "Countess" "Don"      "Dr"       "Jonkheer" "Lady"     "Major"    "Master"   "Miss"   "Mlle"     "Mme"      "Mr"       "Mrs"      "Ms"       "Rev"      "Sir"
```

All values present in the test set:

```
levels(as.factor(y$Salutation))
[1] "Col"    "Dona"   "Dr"     "Master" "Miss"   "Mr"     "Mrs"    "Ms"     "Rev"
```

The salutation "Dona" screws up my decision tree when I try to predict the ages on the test set

Comment: It's always puzzled me why people think there should be an answer to this. You are asking for a prediction on something that you gave no information about to the algorithm. Or are you having difficulty removing the oddball cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As BondedDust pointed out there is no way to know what "Dona" could possibly imply. However, You could mark such observation as "NA" which is something that decision trees can handle. Then depending on Your problem formulation You can

1. Output NA age for those whose Salutations is NA
2. Substitute overall mean of age to those who have NA salutation
3. Possibly, substitute mean age of those that have NA salutation in train set to those who have NA salutation in test set

What is appropriate depends on data source, whether You have other variables, what is the evaluation metrics, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is, if your training set is large enough, and if you can afford to drop the data which doesn't have a feature set needed, you do so. Delete that particular row of data. I did it many times, when My training data set is huge.

Comment: The "problem" row is in the test data, not the training data... Dropping or adding similar training data won't fix the problem of new feature values in the test data